# Advice on linking product codes to a product in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I need some advice of how to setup my tables I currently have a product table and a product codes table.

In the codes table I have an id and a title such as:

```
1 567902
2 345789
3 345678
```

there can be many items in this table.

In my product table I have the usual product id,title, etc but also a code id column that I'm currently storing a comma separate list of ids for any codes the product needs to reference.

in that column I could end up with ids like: 2,5,6,9

I'm going to need to be able to search the products table looking for code ids for a specific set this is where I've come into problems trying to use id IN ($var) or FIND_IN_SET is proving problematic I've been advised to restructure it I'm happy to do just wondering what the best method would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have two choices.  If this is a 1 to many relationship, then you need to have the foreign key in the `code` table, not the `product` table.

i.e.

```
codeId code   productId
1      567902 2
2      345789 6
3      345678 9
4      345690 9
```

The other option is to have another table which contains productId and codeId (both as foreign keys), this is a many-to-many relationship.  This is what you should go for if a code can be assigned to multiple products (I assume not). It will look something like this:

```
codeId productId
1      2
1      10
2      6
3      9
4      9
```

I think the first option is what you need.

Comment: yes I think it is a 1 to many there would only be one code that that would be referenced in many products. How would I store more then 1 productId in the productCodes table?

Comment: It would be another row.  I have modified the answer to include a product with two codes.

Comment: ah of course! the codes can be in various products its kind of like a category in a sense. Thanks I know what I need to do now should have asked this hours ago rather trying to get my version working.

Comment: No worries @Dave.  The good thing about trying it first is that you will remember this next time ;).